# Getting Password From X509Certificate2 or Storing Password Securely

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, x509certificate2, azure-api-management

I have a wpf application which is able to create and start Azure services on demand. For API calls, the client needs to have a valid certificate. As an authentication method, the application asks for a .pfx certificate, and the password when staring. Using the password and the pfx file, I create an X509Certificate2, and then send all api calls using this certificate. I do not store the password itself. Now, when creating an Azure Service, I want to upload the certificate in the .pfx format (this is required by my worker role), and for this I need to send the password too. Now, since the user is already being asked for a password at the beginning, I do not want to ask again, when creating the service. Is there a way I can get the password from already existing X509Certificate2 object, or do I really need to save the password somewhere.

Comment: You cannot get it out. Otherwise, everyone else also could have.

Comment: I dislike the whole design in this thread. Server SHALL NOT have knowledge about client's private key. It is really BAD. What you should do is to initiate a client certificate-based authentication by using IIS/API means. And, of course, server SHALL have its own server certificate to authenticate himself.